# Generate yearly time series

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, simulation

I've 5 years of historical hourly wind-speeds for a certain location available. 
What I need to do is to estimate the distribution of the yearly average wind speed.  What method do I need such that I can generate, for instance, 1000 samples for which I can calculate the yearly average wind speed?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,
Matthijs